# I am trying to running Apache-NiFi on one server and my postgresql is on another server

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from postgresql database using NIiFi . I am using Quertdatabase processor . I connected database but there is problem . NiFi running but data not fetched from postgresql.
this is my configuration for DBCP connection Pool.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dka4.png)
this is correct which i am using.

please give solution

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? You may need to download the driver onto the NiFi node(s) and point at the local file instead of at a web URL, I think we fixed that but in more recent versions if at all

Comment: I am using NiFi version 1.23.2 and I download jdbc derive jar file on NiFi node . My data base driver location is- /root/nifi-1.23.2/lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar  and my postgreSQL installed same ip where I installed nifi. PostgreSQL version is 15.4.1  .

Comment: Please give me solution.

Comment: How is your QueryDatabaseTable processor configured? What does your table look like?